# Spring Rest Controller Exception Handling for invalid parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

I am writing a simple api but want to add custom exception handling for when invalid parameters are passed in (i.e. x and y are inputted as strings)

I have searched all over but can only find custom exception handling for no results being found etc.

```
@RestController
public class DivideApi {

    @GetMapping("/divide")
    public DivideApiResponse getAns(@RequestParam int x, int y){
        DivideInt divInt = new DivideInt();

        int ans = divInt.divide(x, y);

        return new DivideApiResponse(
                false, 200, "" + x + "*" + y + "=" + ans, x, y, ans
        );
    }
}
```

How would I go about handling such an error?

Answer (score 0):

What is usually done - is general exception handling using @ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {DivideApi.class})
public class ExceptionHandler{...}
```

There You can declare methods that would intercept particular exceptions:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorDTO handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    LOGGER.debug("MethodArgumentNotValidException: ", e);
    //ErrorDTO is Your custom error with custom messages etc. You can return whatever you like
    return new ErrorDTO(ErrorConstants.ERR_BAD_INPUT_PARAMETER, multiLangMessages, ErrorType.CLIENT_ERROR);
}
```

In my case it's MethodArgumentNotValidException. You intercept what does it throw to you.